# Java monitoring/metrics solution that stores metrics to disk at the node level

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I am looking for a metrics/monitoring library where each node/host publishes its metrics to disk, and the central aggregator pulls the data as needed to create graphs and run queries.

The reasoning behind these requirements, is that I don't want the server/aggregator to be running all the time. I only want to run it when I need to query it or generate a dashboard. I also don't want to lose data when the server is not running.

As far as I can tell, Prometheus does not support that, is that correct? Prometheus does not persist ANY data at the node level. Data is pulled by the server and is then persisted. When the server is not running, the data gets lost.

Is there another open source library I can use that does that? Looking ideally for something that's compatible with grafana.

Comment: Recomendation of libraries are off topic in Stackoverlow.